# How to print out a line based on width and height using dots (.)

Tags: java, class

I'm using a class file that has mutator and accessor methods for both Height and Width. Thats not my problem. I have an accessor method for my draw method here:

```
public class Screen()
...
...
public String draw(String draw)
{
 draw = ".";
 return draw;
}
```

How can I call for this method based on my width and height? Such as, Height = 4  Width = 4.
 Forming a 4 x 4 box out of dots.

Comment: nested for loops should solve this for ya

Answer (score 1):

Use a nested `for` loop. In the inner loop, use `print`, not `println`, that way all of the width dots appear on the same line. After the inner loop completes, call `println` with no contents to create a line return. You will also need to change your function declaration to include the correct variables. In this case, you need 2 `int` values that correspond to the width and height of the box that you wish to draw.

```
public static void drawBox(int height, int width){
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++){
            System.out.print(".");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Using that function, I called:

```
drawBox(4,4);
```

And I got the output of:

```
....
....
....
....
```

Comment: I appreciate it. I will experiment with this usage. Thanks, again. I never knew I could appropriate for loops within a class with no main.